# 500 Error: Failed to establish a backside connection on bluemix java liberty app

Tags: ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I deployed my java web application on Bluemix Dedicated environment and use it with Cloudant Dedicated NoSql DB. In this DB i tried to return 60k documents and server returned

`500 Error: Failed to establish a backside connection`

to me. So i'm wondering about connection timeout in Bluemix, there're posts where people claim that Bluemix resets a network connection in 120 if there's no response received. Is it possible to change this setting, or maybe someone knows how to solve such problem.

P.S. When I deploy it on my computer then it works fine, but of course it takes some time. Particularly this case may be solved using cloudant pagination, but i develop service for scheduling REST-calls and if bluemix reset all connections after 2 minutes i'll have a big problems with it.

Comment: See also: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/296255/500-error-failed-to-establish-a-backside-connectio-7.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which Bluemix Dedicated you are using, but the timeout is typically global.  Paging would work and I thinking a websocket based approach would work as well.

-r